# Can I select a single row in Slick that is also guaranteed to be the only row returned?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

In Slick, there are `first` and `firstOption` to select the first row of your result set.

Is there a version that also guarantees that this was the only row being returned (so that I get an exception if the dataset somehow breaks certain assumptions my application depends on)?

Comment: Not sure if you're looking for something that will validate the operation before it is run on the DB (which is impossible, as far as I can tell) or something which will give you an error when your calls give you other than the expected affected row count.  If the latter, you may want to take a look at [activeslick's `DBIOExtensions`](https://github.com/strongtyped/active-slick/blob/23dd36020bedb79a4c86683324b34c87eb140f05/modules/core/src/main/scala/io/strongtyped/active/slick/DBIOExtensions.scala#L8)

Comment: @SeanVieira: the latter. I'd like the same feature that many other ORM solutions offer to select a single row (select 2, check that there was only 1, error out if too many)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of anything built in to do that. What you can do is write a method that will take an action, check the results is exactly one row, and fail if it isn't.

That could just be a plain old method you wrap around an action. Or, we could enrich an action so it becomes a call you make on an action. Here's an example of the kind of thing I mean:

```
implicit class ResultEnrichment[T](action: DBIO[Seq[T]]) {
  def exactlyOne: DBIO[T] = action.flatMap { xs =>
    xs.length match {
      case 1 => DBIO.successful(xs.head)
      case n => DBIO.failed(new RuntimeException(s"Expected 1 result, not $n"))
    }
  }
}
```

This class is marked as implicit so the compiler can make use of it whenever there's a `DBIO[Seq[T]]`. Specifically, it supplies an `exactlyOne` method which the compiler can find on any action of `Seq[T]`.

The result of `exactlyOne` is a new action you can run.  It will fail if it doesn't find exactly one row at runtime.

You'd use it like this for some arbitrary query:

```
val query = table.filter(...).map(...) // whatever your query is
val action = query.result.exactlyOne
```

Run that final `action` and you'll get one result or an error at runtime.